# Decide which tomcat webapp handles the requests, depending on the URL entered

Tags: web-applications, tomcat

I have 2 different webapps running under the same tomcat instance, and want to separate which requests each one handles depending on the URL from which the user comes from.

For example, if the user types in www.example.com, webapp1 handles everything. If the users types in www.example.co.uk, webapp2 handles it.

Both webapps run in the same apache tomcat instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html should help.